# How to avoid "too many redirects" error when using readLines(url) in R?

Tags: r, url, text-mining

I am trying to mine news articles from various sources by doing

```
site = readLines(link)
```

link being the url of the site I am trying to download. Most of the time this works but with some specific sources I get the error:

```
Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(con, "r") : too many redirects, aborting ...
```

Which I'd like to avoid but so far I had no success in doing so.

Replicating this is quite easy as virtually none of the New York Times links work

e.g. http://www.nytimes.com/2014/08/01/us/politics/african-leaders-coming-to-talk-business-may-also-be-pressed-on-rights.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the NYT site forces redirects for cookie and tracking purposes. Looks like the built-in URL reader isn't able to deal with them correctly (not sure if it supports cookies which is probably the problem).

Anyway, you might consider using the `RCurl` package to access the file instead. Try

```
library(RCurl)
link  = "http://www.nytimes.com/2014/08/01/us/politics/african-leaders-coming-to-talk-business-may-also-be-pressed-on-rights.html?_r=0"

site <- getURL(link, .opts = curlOptions(
    cookiejar="",  useragent = "Mozilla/5.0", followlocation = TRUE
))
```

Comment: Thanks! That seems to have done it. I restarted the mining process as further examination showed that many of the old ones got stuck at precursor pages, hopefully this will also fix that.